# Laravel - Como chamar vários métodos passando a mesma rota?

Tags: laravel

Quando eu passo as duas acaba *bugando* a outra e vice-versa.

***Exemplo:***

```
Route::get('/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}','PsicologoControlador@edit');
Route::get('/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}','ControladorMunicipioUf@ListaUfEditar');
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso. Você terá que chamar sua outra função por meio de apenas um controller.

Comment: Se forem iguais, o laravel priorizará uma

Answer (score 0):

Não pode escrever a mesma rota para dois ou mais `controller` e `métodos` diferentes. Cada rota que é configurado é também única dentro do projeto, mas, diferente disso pode escrever diversas rotas diferentes para o mesmo `controller` e método, ***exemplo***:

**Isso funciona:**

```
Route::get('/psicologo/busca/{psi_codigo}','PsicologoControlador@edit');
Route::get('/psicologo/filter/{psi_codigo}','PsicologoControlador@edit');
```

porque são rotas diferentes apontado para o mesmo `controller` e método.

***Não funciona***

```
Route::get('/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}','PsicologoControlador@edit');
Route::get('/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}','ControladorMunicipioUf@ListaUfEditar');
```

porque as rotas são iguais (e deveria ser únicas) apontando para diversos `controllers` e métodos.

**Resumindo:** *cada rota é única no seu projeto, onde a repetição das rotas  faz com que o projeto só faça funcionar uma delas.*

Comment: meu problema é o seguinte. ao editar eu chamo essa rota Route::get('/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}','PsicologoControlador@edit'); porém eu tenho uma lista de Estados(UF) que deverá ser listar em um componente select.  e esse método que lista os estados está no controler ControladorMunicipioUf cujo o método é ListaUfEditar. como faço para chamar esse método dentro da rota que informei acima?

Comment: @user9078159 chama no método! agora duplicar rota não pode. eu expliquei o problema

Comment: eu fiz isso aqui. porém ainda não encontra a variavel     public function edit($id)
    {
        $psi = Psicologo::find($id);
        if(isset($psi)){
            return view('editarPsicologo',compact('psi'));
            $ListaUfEditar = Estado::find($id);
            return view('editarPsicologo',compact('ListaUfEditar'));

 
        } return redirect('/psicologo'); 
      
  
    }

Comment: conseguir!! fiz dessa forma.      */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $psi = Psicologo::find($id);
        $ListaUfEditar = Estado::all();
        if(isset($psi)){
            return view('editarPsicologo',compact('psi','ListaUfEditar'));
        } return redirect('/psicologo'); 
      
  
    }

Answer (score -3):

```
Route::get('/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}','PsicologoControlador@edit');
Route::get('/psicologo/editar/','ControladorMunicipioUf@ListaUfEditar');
```